# System storage is showing full even when it is not. So I can't install apk as system app

Tags: adb, storage, insufficient-memory, system, system-apps

I have OnePlus 6 with latest Open Beta. It is rooted. I have done everything but I still can't install any app as a system app.

I have tried Link2SD and Titanium Backup. I have tried to copy/paste the apk using TWRP file manager and ES file Explorer. I have tried to move the apk using adb shell. Everything is giving the same error that /system has no space left.

Link2SD storage shows
[image]

Settings storage shows
[image]

Why it is giving me memory error when system has space?

Comment: Use the Magisk module app systemizer

Comment: systemizer isn't working. But even so why does it shows my system storage is full when its not?

Comment: yes the system storage is full. But how can it be full I have just flashed my phone twice. Does that mean I can not get updates for system apps that are bigger than the current size?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the list to see what is taking so much space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... /system has no space left.

It indicates that your `/system` partition is mounted R/W but just to make sure, if `dm-verity` is enabled, `/system` is always R/O. For details see [How to disable dm-verity on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215907/218526).

Next, both of your screenshots show that your `/system` partition is full. Even if you haven't written anything to it, some ROMs may have `/system` already completely filled. After all it isn't for user's usage.

The space shown as "System" in Settings isn't actually the `/system` partition. In fact it can't be of 11GB, that's too much. Android is counting a large data from `/data` partition also as "System", because it's not what a "user" directly puts there. User can access only shared/external storage (`/sdcard`).

You can check actually space usage of `/system` partition with command `df -h /system`. Execute `du -h /system | sort -h` to get a directory-wise detail of what's taking up space.

For more details, see [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)