# How to disable dm-verity on Android with "user" build type ROM?

Tags: root-access, file-system, linux, selinux, dm-verity

I have One Plus 6T Android device which has a ROM of build type `user`. This device is rooted with Magisk and I want to disable `dm-verity` on this device. I have tried to run `adb disable-verity` but I got an error saying `verity cannot be disabled/enabled - USER build`

Is there any way to disable this?

Goal: Want to place customized `sepolicy` file under `system_root` directory. I have tried to do it with following commands:

```
C:\Users\GPU-Test>adb shell
OnePlus6T:/ $ su
OnePlus6T:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system_root
OnePlus6T:/ # cp /sdcard/selinux_policy_modified /system_root/sepolicy
cp: /system_root/sepolicy: Permission denied
1|OnePlus6T:/ # cp -f /sdcard/selinux_policy_modified /system_root/sepolicy
cp: /system_root/sepolicy: No such file or directory
1|OnePlus6T:/ # ^C
130|OnePlus6T:/ # exit
130|OnePlus6T:/ $ exit

C:\Users\GPU-Test>adb disable-verity
verity cannot be disabled/enabled - USER build
```

Also tried to disable `Preserve force encryption` and `Preserve AVB 2.0/dm-verity` checkbox but still the above commands have same result. Also on reboot these check-boxes enables again automatically.

Comment: can you please be more specific what your question is targeting, because usually you have already patched your device against dm-verity (Magisk Manager has a checkbox for)?

Comment: I have added more detail regarding why I want to do this and what I have tried.

Comment: why not use `/` instead of `/system_root`?

Comment: @alecxs on system-as-root devices Magisk mounts recovery ramdisk at `/`, not `system` partition. `/` is volatile filesystem.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks, "recovery" was the missing piece! Now this article makes sense to me "Magisk mounts system to ‘/system_root’ and bind mount ‘/system_root/system’ to ‘/system.’ " https://www.xda-developers.com/magisk-google-pixel-3-pixel-3a-android-q

Comment: @alecxs with Q things have again changed. Now `system` partition will be monuted at `/` but the files to be modified/added (e.g. `init`, `init.rc`, `/sbin`) will be overlaid using bind mounts. In each case target is to be *system-less* and *detection-less*.

Comment: I think I need to place `sepolicy` file directly into `system.img` and then flash it via `fastboot system system.img` command. I have tried lots of tutorial-like https://www.china-devices.com/forum/index.php?threads/how-to-properly-unpack-and-repack-android-system-img-for-sp-flash-tool.18739/ but I get an error like "Invalid sparse file format at header magi \n Failed to read sparse file
". I think these all tutorial are deprecated for new android images. Do you guys have any idea about any tool that can extract `system.img`?

Comment: @VatishSharma modifying `system.img` isn't a big deal but it makes no difference. Device won't boot with modified `system.img` if `dm-verity` is enabled. Let me write answer for you what you can try to disable `dm-verity`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm going to give a general overview of how `dm-verity` and related things work on Android according to my limited knowledge. Situation might differ on different devices and ROMs.

**HOW IS DM-VERITY ENFORCED?**

`dm-verity` ([Verified Boot](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/) and [AVB](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/avb)) as well as `dm-crypt` ([FDE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk)) are targets of [`device-mapper`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper) feature of Linux kernel. `dm-verity` verifies the integrity of each block as they are read from block device; enforced by `init_first_stage` as per `fs_mgr_flags` set in fstab <sup>([1](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity))</sup>. On [system-as-root](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root) devices (`A/B` and `non-A/B`), kernel is [patched](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root#setting-up-dm-verity) to force verity while mounting `/system` and `/vendor` if `verify`/`avb` flags are found in fstab device tree (dtb).
`dm-crypt` decrypts/encrypts data transparently when read/written from/to block device. [FBE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) is based on a different kernel framework `fscrypt`; but both are managed by [`vold`](http://oopsmonk.github.io/blog/2016/04/29/android-full-disk-encryption-workflow) (which runs as a native service) if `fs_mgr_flags` contain `voldmanaged`.

**WHERE FSTAB IS?**

`fstab` has traditionally been a file on Linux to specify filesystems to be mounted on boot. It's a core component of `fs_mgr` functionality on Android.

On pre-Oreo releases `fstab` was in `ramdisk`. With Treble it was moved to `/vendor` (or `/system/vendor`) while the fstab entries for `system` and `vendor` (and `odm`) are moved to Device Tree Blob (`dtb`). Kernel exports `dtb fstab` entries in device tree directory at `/proc/device-tree/firmware/android`.

Some OEMs also put `fstab` in `odm` or `nvdata` partitions.

**Source:** [Android Storage Device Configuration](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config)

**WHERE DTB IS?**

[Device Tree](https://www.devicetree.org/) is a data structure for describing hardware which is not discoverable to kernel. Device Tree Source (`dts`) can be converted to `dtb` (binary blob of DT) and vice versa using [`dtc`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dtc/dtc.git). DTB is loaded by bootloader at boot time and passed to kernel so that it can discover hardware and create device nodes accordingly.

DTB is either:

- Appended to kernel `zImage` or `Image.gz` in `boot.img` <sup>([2](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions-images#kernel-images))</sup>. It can be split from `gzip` archive using [`split-appended-dtb (sadtb)`](https://github.com/dianlujitao/split-appended-dtb).
- Or in `dtbo` partition as some OEMs do. This can be checked with:

  ```
  ~# ls -l /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/dtbo*
  ~# grep -C5 PARTNAME=dtbo /sys/dev/block/*/uevent | grep DEVNAME | sed 's/.*=//; s|^|/dev/block/&|'
  ```
- Or at the end of `boot.img` after 2nd stage, or in `odm` partition (rare, some OEMs do).

Also if the device is `non-A/B`, `dtb` (from `boot.img` and/or `dtbo` partition) is also added to `recovery.img` in DTBO section after header, kernel, ramdisk and 2nd stage <sup>([3](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/recovery-image))</sup>. However this doesn't matter for normal boot. But if the device is also `system-as-root`, Magisk needs to be installed in this recovery partition as the `boot.img` contains no `ramdisk` <sup>([4](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#magisk-in-recovery))</sup>.

In case if DTB is not appended to kernel, `dtb(s)` are converted to `dtb.img` using [`mkdtimg`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/libufdt/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/utils/README.md#mkdtimg). Same tool can dump back the image.

**Source:** [Implementing DTO](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/dto/implement)

**HOW TO DISABLE DM-VERITY?**

On `userdebug` ROMs, `dm-verity` can be disabled using `adb`. It modifies magic number of verity metadata block <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/adb/set_verity_enable_state_service.cpp#191), [6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/libfec/fec_private.h#54))</sup> which is written after the last filesystem block on block device (`system` or `vendor`) <sup>([7](https://www.kynetics.com/docs/2018/introduction-to-dm-verity-on-android/))</sup>. Quoted from [here](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity#metadata):

> the absence of this magic number will halt the verification process

In case of AVB, `adb` modifies `vbmeta header` to disable hashtree image verification <sup>([8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/adb/set_verity_enable_state_service.cpp#174), [9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/libavb/avb_vbmeta_image.h#53))</sup>. Quoted from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md#handling-dm_verity-errors):

> if the `AVB_VBMETA_IMAGE_FLAGS_HASHTREE_DISABLED` flag is set in the top-level vbmeta, then `androidboot.veritymode` is set to **disabled**

On `user` builds `ro.debuggable` is `0` and `adbd` isn't running as root. Also there are other differences like that of [`ALLOW_ADBD_DISABLE_VERITY`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/adb/Android.mk#349), so `adb` won't disable `dm-verity`. Other approach is to remove **`verify`** or **`avb`** <sup>([10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_fstab.cpp#96))</sup> flag from `fstab`. Quoted from [here](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity#signing):

> To verify the partition...
>   ...
>       In the fstab for the relevant entry, add `verify` to the `fs_mgr` flags.

Similarly to remove encryption, `forceencrypt=`, `forcefdeorfbe=` or `fileencryption=` need to be replaced with `encryptable=`. However encryption cannot be removed without factory reset (FBE too?), so unchecking `Preserve force encryption` in Magisk app will do nothing.

Some OEMs also use [`support_scfs`](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63209803&postcount=9) `fs_mgr` flag and `ro.config.dmverity=true` property on devices with `dm-verity` enabled.

There are also some [exploits](https://www.xda-developers.com/exploit-qualcomm-edl-xiaomi-oneplus-nokia/) discovered in [bootloader](https://www.xda-developers.com/two-critical-oneplus-33t-bootloader-security-flaws-discovered-one-patched-and-other-being-addressed/) and [adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/oneplus-root-access-backdoor/) implementation of some OEMs which can be used to disable `dm-verity` on affected devices. However such security flaws usually get fixed over time with updates from OEMs.

**OPTION 1**
Set options in configuration file before installing Magisk:

```
~# echo 'KEEPVERITY=false' >/cache/.magisk
~# echo 'KEEPFORCEENCRYPT=true' >>/cache/.magisk
```

If installed, after unchecking `Preserve AVB v2.0/dm-verity` in app, Magisk needs to be reinstalled. Quoted from [here](https://androbuggers.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/magisk-the-complete-root-manager-app/):

> in Magisk Manager, “Uninstall > Restore Images” to restore the images, check “Preserve AVB 2.0/dm-verity” box in Advanced Settings, then reinstall Magisk via the app.

**OPTION 2**
Use some `dm-verity` disabler zips like [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/universal-dm-verity-forceencrypt-t3817389).

**OPTION 3**
Figure out where the `fstab` entries of `/system` and `/vendor` are on your device.

If in `ramdisk` (pre-Treble):

- Extract `ramdisk`, modify `fstab` and repack.
- Or patch `ramdisk` directly:

  ```
  ~# magiskboot cpio ramdisk.cpio 'patch false true'
  ```

If in `dtb`:

- If appended to kernel:

  - Extract `boot.img`
  - Split appended `dtb(s)`
  - Patch `dtb(s)`.
  - Append `dtb(s)` to kernel
  - Repack `boot.img`
- If in `dtbo` partition or in `boot.img` after 2nd stage, patch `dtb.img` and write back to partition or `boot.img`.

**How to Unpack / Repack Boot or Recovery image and Ramdisk?**
Use [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) or [`magiskboot`](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/tools.html#magiskboot).

**How to Patch `dtb`?**
Patch directly using `magiskboot` or manually convert `dtb` to `dts`, edit `dts` with any text editor to remove `dm-verity` flags, and convert `dts` back to `dtb`.

**RELATED:**

- [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526)
- [Android Device Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565)

Comment: In SAR devices launched with Android 10, I have built a kernel with avb flags(no verity flag found) removed from fsmgr_flags entries and made it permissive. Also empty the vbmeta with verification flag disabled. Is it enough for a dm-verity to be disabled? (I can't test it as twrp is not updated to Android 10 and Idk yet how to mount dynamic partition with rooted adb shell in recovery)

Comment: @VatishSharma Sorry I haven't tested with Android 10, so cannot say anything for sure.

Comment: Do you have idea of mounting dynamic partitions(I have made twrp and get rooted adb shell but yes its not updated for dynamic partitions and so lack mounting features)?

Comment: @VatishSharma no idea.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to disable dm-verity in an AOSP build? I assume it's a makefile value.

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit the Magisk root package to ONLY disable the dm-verity flag. It's literally just commenting out a few lines of Magisk scripts, since the functionality is inherently present in Magisk. Here's the link to such a package: [Download magisk-onlynoveritypatch.zip](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=774072&st=30820#entry97055331) Boot into twrp, install from zip, and select this zip.

Comment: thx for sharing. unfortunately only registered users can download. and it's hard to register because there is no english captcha :(