# How to unpack/repack system.img of android ROM?

Tags: root-access, file-system, linux, selinux, aosp

I have OnePlus 6T device which has A/B partition system and has a ROM of user type i.e `[ro.build.type]: [user]`. This device is rooted with Magisk. I have a requirement([Want to place customized sepolicy file under system_root directory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215800/how-to-disable-dm-verity-on-android-with-user-type-rom?noredirect=1#comment276509_215800)) to modify `system.img`.

I have tried different tools like:

1. [simg2img](https://www.china-devices.com/forum/index.php?threads/how-to-properly-unpack-and-repack-android-system-img-for-sp-flash-tool.18739/) :

```
OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea/img-tools$ ./simg2img system.img sys.raw
Invalid sparse file format at header magi
Failed to read sparse file
OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea/img-tools$
```

2. [imgtools](http://newandroidbook.com/tools/imgtool.html)

```
OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea/imgtool$ sudo ./imgtool system.img extract
[sudo] password for OMEN: 
system.img is not a recognized image. Sorry
OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea/imgtool$
```

3. and more tools even on windows..

but none of them is capable of parsing my `system.img`.

I have copied `system.img` directly from OnePlus6T ROM setup which installs Android 9 on this device without any issue.

Any help on:

1. How to fix the system.img so it will be extracted and repacked fine?
2. Any command that can unpack/repack system.img?
3. Any working tool to accomplish this task?

**Update 1**: I have run `file system.img` and I found that its ext2 image and the tools support ext4.

```
system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=d09c08e9-628d-590e-a610-3a14de2a8db0 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

**Update 2**: Tried to find the magic number and have following result:

```
OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea/imgtool$ xxd system.img | head
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea/imgtool$
```

**Update 3** Fing the image already unpacked. So to add the required file, I have mount the image as `sudo mount -o loop system.img system_mount` and then tried to copy the contents to another folder with `cp system_mount/* system/` so that I can add the required file and make new image out of it but I got following errors:

```
root@OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea# mkdir system && cp system_mount/* system/
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/acct'
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/bin': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/bt_firmware': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/bugreports': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/cache': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/charger': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/charger_log': No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/config'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/d'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/data'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/dev'
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/dsp': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/etc': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/firmware': No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/lost+found'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/mnt'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/odm'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/oem'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/op1'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/op2'
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/persist': No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/postinstall'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/proc'
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/product': No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/res'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/sbin'
cp: cannot stat 'system_mount/sdcard': No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/storage'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/sys'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/system'
cp: omitting directory 'system_mount/vendor'
root@OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-dc0xxx:~/WorkArea#
```

Comment: Does the system.img you have start with hex `3AFF 26ED`? If not check if the file header magic bytes is something known.

Comment: It is showing as 00 00 00 00.. Please check the **Update 2**.

Comment: Looks like the image is already unpacked.

Comment: Oh really :o So, how to add a file in this .img file?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it is obvious to mount an ext2/4 file if you want to modify it.

Comment: Mounting has some problem. Let me add it to the question.

Comment: Are you sure the mount command failed? These messages look more like warnings to me.

Comment: use `busybox cp -acv` instead of `cp` if you want to preserve permissions. selinux enabled (x86_64) binary of [busybox](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/tool-busybox-flashable-archs-t3348543) (works on pc) `sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw,noatime system.img system_mount` works only when directory system_root exist in same location as system.img

Comment: @Robert because of your advice I downloaded Ubuntu and was able to extract all the files from the img file. Do you know how to pack it back?

Answer (score 7):

**These commands don't work always: sometimes the system_new.img size becomes greater than system.img.ext4 and hence it doesn't flash on the device. As per my knowledge, the new image size should be equal to or less than the size of the original system image. ---- If anyone will be able to determine the new commands then please share it.**

To Unpack-Modify-Pach the `system.img`, I have followed the following procedure:

a) **Unpacking**

- Run `file system.img` and make sure that `system.img` is Android Sparse Image.
- Rename `system.img` to `system.img.ext4`. // Not required if you will use other name for raw image in below steps.
- With `simg2img system.img.ext4 system.img`, you will get a raw image file named `system.img`
- With `mkdir system`, create directory to mount system.img
- With `sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img system/` you will get all files of `system.img` in `system` folder

b) **Modifying**

- With `ls -l system/init.rc` note permissions: 750
- With `sudo chmod 777 system/init.rc` give write permissions
- With `sudo echo "#MODIFICATION " >> system/init.rc` done some modification in `init.rc`
- With `sudo chmod 750 init.rc` reset `init.rc` to the noted permissions

c) **Calculate system sector size**

- With `tune2fs -l system.img | grep "Block size\|Block count"` you will get block size and count
- With `echo $((1553064 * 4096))` multiply both results. I got 6361350144

d) **Packing**

- With `sudo make_ext4fs -s -l 6361350144 -a system system_new.img system/` you will get `system_new.img` “Android Sparse Image” that has all changes

Comment: Getting 'can't set android permissions - built without android support' error when executing the packing command. Any idea?

Comment: Never get this error. Probably using another(or previous version of) `make_ext4fs` tool can resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Could you please tell me what is the 'sys/' mentioned in the tail of the packing command means?

Comment: It should be `system/` means the folder in which raw `system.img` extracted. Fixed it in the answer as well.

Comment: These commands don't work always: sometimes the `system_new.img` size becomes greater than `system.img.ext4` and hence it doesn't flash on the device. As per my knowledge, the new image size should be equal to or less than the size of the original system image. ---- If anyone will be able to determine the new commands then please share it with me too.

Comment: Maybe it is just that you need to specify a bigger size when using the `-l` flag. The file provided should be the total size needed to store the whole new folder.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and it works:

```
truncate --size=3000M system.img
mke2fs -t ext4 -L system_rw system_rw.img
sudo mount system_rw.img
sudo cp -R --preserve=all /path_to_the_ronly_system.img_mountpoint/. /system_rw_mountpoint
```

Example for `cp`: `sudo cp -R --preserve=all /media/user/_/. /media/user/system_rw/`

That's all folks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool on linux, I was able to extract the image of my emulator using ext4 on vm running ubuntu.

https://github.com/qmfrederik/extfstools

Still figuring out a way to pack it back. 
Will update here once I am able to do it

Comment: Why not simply `mount`? Repacking is simple. Create sparse file with `truncate`. Do `mkfs.ext4` and `mount`. Add files and `umount`. No special tools needed. But how would you preserve permissions, ownership, timestamps, xattr of files this way?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I don't know how to mount on VM. and b) I am noob at ubuntu. Installed vm last night. c) Until last night permissions etc were alien to me. I just need to run a small app on auto on a server on emulator so I don't think i need to worry about permissions but i do want to provide root access to some apps . Do you mind having a chat about it and helping me out ?

Comment: Chat on what? Ask a question specifically if not answered already. For Linux/Android basics do some research and study. I'm available to help if not available otherwise.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I am unable to create an image for android 7.1.1 which actually works on emulator. I am extracting image of an emulator as well.