# Stuck in boot-loop when unpack and pack `system.img`?

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, linux, selinux, aosp

**Background:** I have a **treble** and **system-as-root** but it is not an **A/B** Samsung device. I am trying to modify the `system.img`. Before that, I have rooted it with the steps given [here](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root). After following these steps, I get a valid AP file that I can flash with BL, CP and HOME_CSC file using Odin. The result of the flashing is a rooted device with a recovery key combination.

I don't want to always press the key combination to get root so, I have asked following questions on this site:

- [How to patch `system.img` using MagiskManager patch feature to root the device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218264/how-to-patch-system-img-using-magiskmanager-patch-feature-to-root-the-device?noredirect=1#comment281206_218264)
- [How to boot system-as-root device always as rooted?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218222/how-to-boot-system-as-root-device-always-as-rooted)

**Problem:** To achieve the system root, I have to modify the system file of the `magisk_patched.tar` file. So, I have extracted it and tried the following things:

A) **Success in Try**

1. Unpack and pack the `magisk_patched.tar` file. This confirms that the `tar` commands to pack and unpack is working fine.
2. Unpack, remove the `meta-data`(which contains a suspicious password-protected `fota.zip` file) and pack the `magisk_patched.tar` file. From this, I have assumed that the `fota.zip` is not creating any problem(listed below in B)) when modifying `system.img`.
3. Unpack, compress `*.img`(patched files by Magisk) with lz4 and pack the `magisk_patched.tar` file. This confirms that the `lz4` compression is working fine with Odin.

B) **Failure in Try**

1. Making tar file with unpacked system partition with no modification:

   - Unpack the `magisk_patched.tar`
   - Uncompress the `system.img.ext4.lz4`
   - Convert the `system.img.ext4`(Android Sparse Image) to `system.img`(Raw Image)
   - Mount `system.img` to the system folder
   - Created `system.img.ext4`(Android Sparse Image) from mounted folder using `make_ext4` utils
   - Replace new `system.img.ext4` with `system.img.ext4.lz4` in the extracted `magisk_patched.tar` folder
   - Created a new `AP.tar` from the extracted `magisk_patched.tar` folder
   - Flashed this AP with BL, CP and HOME_CSC(in CSC section) using Odin.
   - Flashing completed.
   - Reboot the device in recovery mode and wiped data partition.
   - Reboot the device with recovery key combinations and released the keys on the splash screen.
   - The device stuck in a boot loop.
2. Used `lz4` in place of `system.img.ext4` as follows:

   - Followed the same step as in 1. till the `system.img.ext4` is created.
   - After that, I compressed it with `lz4` utility and make a `system.img.ext4.lz4`.
   - Replace new `system.img.ext4.lz4` with `system.img.ext4.lz4` in the extracted `magisk_patched.tar` folder
   - Then the same step as in 1. and have the same result.
3. Removed `meta-data` folder from the extracted `magisk_patched.tar` and flash with trying the steps listed in both 1. and 2. but the result is same: The device stuck in a boot loop.

**Commands that I am using:** Please check the accepted answer of [How to unpack/repack system.img of android ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215866/how-to-unpack-repack-system-img-of-android-rom)

So, I will not able to modify and flash it successfully until I will get success in flashing it without modification.

Any solution to this problem or any suggestion to find it out?

**Update 1:** I get the kernel logs via the recovery after a boot loop. In recovery, when a boot loop happens, I can see the file generated as

```
/cache/recovery/last_kmsg
/cache/recovery/last_history
/cache/recovery/last_avc_msg_recovery
/cache/recovery/last_log.1
/cache/recovery/last_kmsg.1
/cache/recovery/last_log.2
/cache/recovery/last_kmsg.2
/cache/recovery/last_log.3
/cache/recovery/last_kmsg.3
and so on where log.* and kmsg.* keeps generating for every boot loop.
```

I have tried to find any kernel panic related string in these files but not seen any such error. Please let me know if I have to look for other words that can be related to a cause of the boot loop?
I can not use adb here as the device is unauthorized so, the only option to check is reading these logs from the phone where I can scroll using up-down volume keys and the touch is not working :(

The only way, I can share these logs is through [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-XNmjpYvH-L8lY0xA0SYr7XcITVCrVS/view?usp=sharing).

In this video, I have done the following:

1. Displayed recovery logs before: The last recovery logs are ends with 8.
2. Rebooted the device with a recovery key combination. I have already wipe data partition before making this video.
3. The boot loop happens and in the next reboot, I have pressed the recovery key combination to open the recovery mode where logs that end with 9 displayed.
4. Then I have recorded `last_history`, `last_avc_message_recovery`, `last_log.9` and `last_kmsg.9`
5. `last_history` and `last_avc_message_recovery` looks unchanged(same as before boot loop).
6. Then, I just have tried to mount the system but that didn't work.
7. At last, I have just rebooted the system normally without any recovery key combination.

Is anyone can help me in debugging the problem by looking at the logs. I have tried to find but I don't have enough knowledge to understand some of the things mentioned in the logs.

**Some Error and Warning logs of last_log.9**

```
exec -f /system/bin/e2fsck -v -y /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache
error: _do_exec: can't run '/system/bin/e2fsck'
  (errno 13 : Permission denied)
/system/bin/e2fsck terminated by exit(255)
...
E:Can't read /cache/recovery/last_locale: No such file or directory
...
W:Failed to unmount /efs: Device or resource busy
can't unmount /efs - Device or resource busy
...
W:Failed to set brightness: Invalid argument
I:Screensaver disabled
Atomic Commit failed in DisableNonMainCrtcs
Atomic Commit failed, rc = 0
...
Reboot Recovery Cause is [[BootChecker]RebootRecoveryWithKey]
...
print_recovery_cause() : reboot_reason=[[BootChecker]RebootRecoveryWithKey]
...
[property list]
persist.audio.fluence.speaker=true
...
ro.vendor.build.security_patch=2018-08-05

Supported API: 3
I:/efs is already mounted
W:Failed to unmount /efs: Device or resource busy
check_selective_file:Can't unmount /efs - Device or resource busy

just_reboot_after_update = 1
should_wipe_cahcewipe_cache

-- Wiping cache...
erase_volume(/cache)
...
MDF_I: Completed reset MDF flag!
MDF_I: Completed initialized MDF for Recovery!
mke2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Discarding device blocksL 4096/153600??????????????????????????????done
Discard takes 0.00051s
Creating filesystem with 153600 4k blocks and 38400 inodes
...
Creating journal (2048 blocks): done
...
copy_logs
...
Cache wipe complete
[Checking pre-multi-csc2]
[start failed section]
sales_code=VZW
Carrier ID=[XAA]

[system partition space check]
The device has /product partition.

[out-recovery]
I:system root image is true, so need to change the unmount point from /system to /system_root
running out-recovery time : 0.000s
running recovery time: 1.738s
copy_avc_msg_to_data(1, )
I:fs_type "ext4" for /cache
copy_file 'proc/avc_msg' 'cache/recovery/last_avc_msg_recovery'
!__RECOVERY_FOR_ASSAMBLY
b_del_recovery_command = true
Rebooting...
## finish_recovery_terminate(del=1, reboot_cmd=reboot, clear_BCB=1)
## finish_recovery(delcmd=1,...
I:Saving locale "en-US"
I:fs_type "ext4" for /cache
I:[libfs_mgr]dt_fstab: Skip disabled entry for partition vm-linux
I:## unlink /cache/recovery/command
copy_logs
I:fs_type "ext4" for /cache
copy_log_file :: create recovery log file '/cache/recovery/log'
copy_log_file :: create recovery log file '/cache/recovery/last_log'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138087/discussion-on-question-by-vatish-sharma-stuck-in-boot-loop-when-unpack-and-pack).