# How to use setprop via adb shell in recovery?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, file-properties, device-name

I messed up flashing a beta Android Q build on my phone.

After that, I can't flash my stable ROM without error 7 in TWRP - device mismatch.
Removing the assert works, but not a permanent solution.

So, I digged through google and my own phone for hours and found out why. My device is identified as `raphael` in recovery, but it is identified as `raphaelin` in `fastboot` and while the phone is booted.

In recovery:

```
# getprop ro.product.device
# raphael
```

In booted mode (i.e. while the phone is booted):

```
# getprop ro.product.device
# raphaelin
```

In fastboot:

```
> fastboot getvar product
product: raphaelin
```

I checked my `build.prop` and the value in that file is `raphaelin` too. I tried `setprop` and it showed that it can't set that property.

So, please advise me on how to set the value using `setprop` in recovery mode. Or, if you know, please let me know from where the recovery is pulling data for `getprop` and if I can change that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the main Android OS (what you call "boot mode") and recovery are two independent operating systems. When one is running, other is not. Running processes are different, environment is different, loaded properties are different and so on.

Recovery has its own `default.prop` file in ramdisk from which it reads properties. In order to permanently change the value of `ro.product.device` you'll have to unpack `recovery.img` (or `boot.img` on [A/B devices](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab/ab_implement#recovery)), modify the file, repack and re-flash.

Secondly you can't set [read-only](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r47/init/property_service.cpp#150) (`ro.*`) properties once they are already set. Magisk's [`resetprop`](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/details.html#resetprop) tool however can do this, going a little out of the way.

Thirdly `ro.product.device` is usually set in [`/system/build.prop`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r47/init/property_service.cpp#759). So you can edit this file and reboot device to see changes. There are also some [other files](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r47/init/property_service.cpp#680) from which properties are set on boot.
<sup>Make sure not to break [`dm-verity`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215907/218526) by modifying `/system` if enabled.</sup>

Since the (`/system` and other) partitions are accessible from recovery mode too, you can mount filesystem read/write in recovery and edit the file.

Fourthly the value you are getting in `fastboot` is independent of both main OS and recovery. That's hard-coded in bootloader. You'll get that value even if there is no recovery and no Android OS on device.