# Can't boot to system after installing TWRP with Odin

Tags: twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

After I installed twrp on a S7 Edge, when I reboot to system I get stuck on a loop that only shows the "Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge" black startup screen for about 8 seconds  and then reboots automatically.

I can get to twrp recovery mode if I press the key combo.

I can even flash the original stock ROM with Odin and start the install process all over again. But still getting the same results...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you download TWRP from?

Comment: I think this site is the official one for twrp downloads: https://dl.twrp.me/hero2lte/

Comment: `dm-verity` would be preventing boot if you allowed System Modification. [Disable dm-verity](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215907/218526)