# What is default "fstab" file in Android?

Tags: file-system, mount

As I known, in Android 9, `system` and `vendor` are mounted in the first stage of `init` by parsing `fstab` from device tree. But, there is another `fstab` parsed in `init` process, it is `device default fstab`, which is parsed by `ReadDefaultFstab` function below. I am facing to a error " failed to find device default fstab " in boot log. Can anyone explain for me this `default fstab` file? What is it and it's role?

```
// Loads the fstab file and combines with fstab entries passed in from device tree.
bool ReadDefaultFstab(Fstab* fstab) {
    Fstab dt_fstab;
    ReadFstabFromDt(&dt_fstab, false);

    *fstab = std::move(dt_fstab);

    std::string default_fstab_path;
    // Use different fstab paths for normal boot and recovery boot, respectively
    if (access("/system/bin/recovery", F_OK) == 0) {
        default_fstab_path = "/etc/recovery.fstab";
    } else {  // normal boot
        default_fstab_path = GetFstabPath();
    }

    Fstab default_fstab;
    if (!default_fstab_path.empty()) {
        ReadFstabFromFile(default_fstab_path, &default_fstab);
    } else {
        LINFO << __FUNCTION__ << "(): failed to find device default fstab";
    }

    for (auto&& entry : default_fstab) {
        fstab->emplace_back(std::move(entry));
    }

    return !fstab->empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be in `/` (ramdisk), `/odm/etc/` or `/vendor/etc/`.

Android Storage [Configuration](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config#file_mappings):

> For Android releases 4.3 and later, the various fstab files used by init, vold and recovery were unified in the `/fstab.<device>` file

Next change occured with Treble when vendor/SoC specific code was separated from Generic AOSP code. So `fstab` was moved to `/odm` or `/vendor`.

`default_fstab_path` reads [`GetFstabPath()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r3/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_fstab.cpp#445):

```
// Identify path to fstab file. Lookup is based on pattern fstab.<hardware>,
// fstab.<hardware.platform> in folders /odm/etc, /vendor/etc, or /.
```

[Commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/46c6dc1a6f10a2a57f79e285af0f166e93a77bb2) states:

> fstab contains device- and soc- specific content that should reside in
>   /odm or /vendor partition. This change searches the fstab.${ro.hardware}
>   file from /odm/etc, /vendor/etc and /, then use the first one found.

`fstab` contains entries for all filesystems to be mounted on boot or in recovery from partitions including `system`, `vendor`, `userdata`, `cache`, `misc`, `persist`, `modem`, `dsp` etc. See details in [Android Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565).

Some of the entries of `fstab` are moved to DTB. See *"WHERE FSTAB IS?"* in [How to disable dm-verity on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215907/218526)