# How to disable USB OTG on Android 6+?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, 8.1-oreo

I need to disable the OTG (USB) on Android 8. I already did it on Android 6 by disabling a permission on the file `android.hardware.usb.host.xml` but it is not working anymore on Android 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`android.hardware.usb.host.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/data/etc/android.hardware.usb.host.xml) file - located under `/vendor/etc/permissions/` or `/system/etc/permissions/` before Treble - contains `feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"` which indicates *that the device can communicate with USB devices as the USB host*. This feature is [evaluated](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#2143) by PackageManager (along with other software / hardware features) and used by Google Play to filter (in)compatible apps based on the value `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />` in *AndroidManifest.xml*. See details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering).

Also if the device doesn't support USB host mode, [UsbHostManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/services/usb/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbService.java#135) service is not started, so apps like [this](https://github.com/Batlin/OTGViewer) which use [USB host APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html) cannot connect to USB devices. But any connected device is still detected by kernel and appears under `/sys` and `/dev`.

To confirm if the device supports USB host mode:

```
~$ pm list features | grep usb.host
feature:android.hardware.usb.host
```

```
~$ dumpsys usb | grep host_manager
  host_manager={
```

These lines shouldn't appear after you delete `android.hardware.usb.host.xml` file.

---

However **since Android 6** USB storage devices such as a USB stick are handled by `vold`, which doesn't depend on the feature discussed above. `vold` listens to kernel through a netlink socket for block device `uevent` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/NetlinkHandler.cpp#52))</sup> and matches that with some entry in `fstab` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/VolumeManager.cpp#197))</sup>. Then it creates disk and partition nodes in `/dev/block/vold/` <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/model/Disk.cpp#307))</sup>, checks filesystem for errors and mounts in `/mnt/media_rw/` (also [emulates SD cards](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526) in `/mnt/runtime/`) <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/model/PublicVolume.cpp#96))</sup>. After that `ExternalStorageProvider` (a content provider) is triggered which grants apps URI access to OTG storage through [SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) or  [Scoped Directory Access](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html).

So in order to disable auto-mounting of USB storage devices by `vold`, you need to **remove the corresponding entry from `fstab`** as referenced [here](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config#portable_storage):

```
/devices/*/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb*    auto    auto    defaults    voldmanaged=usb:auto
```

`fstab` is found under `/odm/etc/` or `/vendor/etc/`. Before Treble it was in rootfs (`/`). See details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217220/218526).

Comment: At least for Android 7 (fstab in /) this does not seem so easy, because the root partition gets rewritten on every reboot, so changing fstab does nothing. It seems you have to unpack boot.img change fstab and pack it again, because on boot, this filesystem gets written to root.

Comment: @user136036 correct.