# Phone Crashing due to too many files/directories on SDCard

Tags: samsung

My Galaxy S9+ running Android 10 crashes whenever I insert my microsd card containing upwards of 9000 sub-directories and 92000 files. The SDCard is using 330GB out of 400GB.

Basically the way this happens is that I insert the sdcard and then a notification displays saying "Checking SanDisk SD card... Reviewing current content

Obviously some kind of timeout is occurring when android attempts to scan the sdcard.
I have tried to disable the scanning a number of ways, making all the sub-directories hidden by prefixing them with a dot, putting a .nomedia file in every sub-directory and by not using any sub-directories and instead having all the files loose in the top level of the sdcard. This last "solution" actually works to stop the crashing but is unacceptable to me.

**Basically my question boils down to this: Is there any way to disable android scanning the sdcard upon boot and when it is inserted ? I have rooted my phone so I could make modifications to the system to achieve this.**

I simply want the sdcard to be usuable like on my linux desktop computer, I insert the sdcard, browse it with a file browser, and that's it. I don't want anything to happen by itself when it is inserted, no scanning, no indexing, nothing!

**The MicroSD Card is formatted as exFAT**

Comment: There is one major problem: the indexing operation builds the AndroidMedia database. This database is the only way to write to the sd-card for apps without root option. A lot of apps also use this database for finding files as direct file-system access is more and more reduced in newer Android versions. Therefore if the sd-card is not indexed then some apps may not be able to find some the files on this card or even add new files.

Comment: I don't need any apps without root access to be able to write to the sd-card, I use rsync with root access to write into the top level of the sd-card or I can just write on the sd-card from my PC. The only app I use to access this sd-card for reading is gonemad media player which can simply access a folder, no indexing required.

Comment: So if you know how to disable this indexing, please let me know ! :)

Comment: Disable auto-mounting of SD card and mount it manually. To disable auto-mounting edit `fstab` (https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217355/218526) or create a small first partition on SD card which gets auto-mounted, and not the second one. Another option is to format the SD card with a filesystem which isn't supported on SD card e.g. `ext4` (https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220020/218526) but it can be mounted manually. Another option is to use a partition ID which isn't supported by `vold`.

Comment: So I am trying what you suggested now, what kind of partition ID is not supported by vold ? making a small first partition on the sdcard surprisingly doesn't stop the phone from auto-mounting in my case, the phone simply mounts both partitions even if one is ext4, and I don't really want to mess with the fstab so I think the partition ID trick could be my best option

Comment: I mentioned partition IDs in the second answer I linked in the above comment which you probably didn't read. Stock Android supports [5 MBR partition IDs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/model/Disk.cpp#387) and [one GPT ID](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/model/Disk.cpp#79). So you can use some other e.g. Linux's ID (`0x83` in case of [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs) ...

Comment: ... or `0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4` in case of [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)). Read `fdisk`/`gdisk` manuals to know how to set these identifiers. // As far as the auto-mounting of second partition is concerned, yes you are correct. Recent Android releases support auto-mounting multiple partitions from SD card or USB. But at least `ext4` is not supported (only `FAT` and `exFAT` are), as evident from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/model/PublicVolume.cpp#114) ...

Comment: ... and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/model/PublicVolume.cpp#341). // Note that some custom ROM developers and OEMs may add support for more partition types and filesystems. See the case of LineageOS [here](https://github.com/AospExtended/platform_system_vold/commit/29a510c99abc2efed45b8ac98583df3543016bfe) and [here](https://github.com/Cardinal-AOSP/system_vold/commit/fe19dbc22d52436a800806a0367d346a9770234a).

Answer (score 0):

Irfran Latif's comment answered my question, I ended up mounting formatting the SDCard as ext4 and mounting it from the command line with appropriate namespaces and permissions.