# How to make Android always use external SD card instead of internal storage?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage, android-emulator, avd-manager

I created an AVD using

```
 bin/avdmanager create avd -d "Nexus 5" -c 2G -n nexus_5 -k "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64"
```

The `-c 2G` is supposed to create a 2GB sdcard.

When I boot the emulator, however, `/sdcard` seems to point to internal storage on `/data/media` rather on the 2GB disk:

```
$ adb shell df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                         996M  604K  996M   1% /dev
tmpfs                         996M     0  996M   0% /mnt
tmpfs                         996M     0  996M   0% /apex
/dev/block/dm-2               2.4G  2.3G   64M  98% /
/dev/block/dm-1               124M  123M  444K 100% /vendor
/dev/block/vdc                775M  302M  473M  39% /data
/data/media                   775M  302M  473M  39% /mnt/runtime/default/emulated
/dev/block/vold/public:253,80 1.9G  532M  1.4G  27% /mnt/media_rw/1400-1801
/mnt/media_rw/1400-1801       1.9G  532M  1.4G  27% /mnt/runtime/default/1400-1801
```

```
$ adb shell ls -l /sdcard /storage/self/primary  /mnt/user/0/primary
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2020-12-01 13:29 /mnt/user/0/primary -> /storage/emulated/0
lrw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 2020-07-21 03:02 /sdcard -> /storage/self/primary
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 2020-12-01 13:28 /storage/self/primary -> /mnt/user/0/primary
```

```
$ adb shell mount | grep storage/emulated
/data/media on /storage/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal)
```

When I try to `adb push` data to `/sdcard` this fails because there’s not sufficient space available (on internal storage).

How can I tell the emulator to use the external sdcard instead?

Comment: That's expected. `/sdcard` isn't physically external SD card. It's a symlink to primary emulated external shared storage. See details in https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526, https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526

Comment: Right, I guess my question is: how can make Android use the 2GB device instead of the smaller one. How do I configure this?

Comment: If you read the answers I linked, you get the answer to your query. Android by-default doesn't use secondary external shared storage. But apps can, if they want.

Answer (score 2):

`/sdcard` isn't physically external SD card but a symlink to ***primary external shared storage***. See details in my answers to [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526) and [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205430)

From your comment:

> How can make Android use the 2GB device instead of the smaller one. How do I configure this?

Android by-default doesn't use ***secondary external shared storage***. But apps can, if they want. See my answer to [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175738).

If you want to make Android always use physical SD card as ***primary external shared storage***, you need to change your ROM's configuration from [Emulated primary only](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example#android_6_emulated) or [Emulated primary, physical secondary](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example#android_6_both) to [Physical primary only](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example#android_6_physical). It's possible by editing the [`fstab` file](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217220/218526) and some [`init`'s `.rc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md) file. Follow the above official documentation links for details on configuration changes.