# Device freezes when try to write in /system partition. None of the mount commands worked

Tags: mount, system, system-freeze, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

I have a TB-X304L. I rooted this guy with magisk and whenever I try to write or try to change permissions of the /system directory, the tablet just freezes and I have to reboot it with long pressing power and the volume up button. I can't even make changes to the build.prop file. The same happens when tried with adb. I could get root access in adb shell. when I try,

```
cat > testfile.txt
```

it says read only partition. So, I mounted it with rw permission command

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

it runs smoothly. But when I try

```
cat > testfile.txt
```

again and type some text for the test file and press Ctrl+D,  it freezes. I am new to all these please help me guys.

Comment: Did you [disable `dm-verity`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215907/218526)?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes. It is disabled in magisk. But force encryption is enabled. Please help. I still can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: With root privileges run: `set -x; id; mount -o rw,remount /system; mount | grep 'on /system '; touch /system/test_file; cat /sys/block/dm-*/dm/name`. Share exact output at https://pastebin.com/