# Cannot edit mixer_paths_tasha.xml on android 10

Tags: root-access, custom-roms

I wanted to edit mixer_paths_tasha.xml to change RX0 value from 84 to 95.
 I am currently using havoc 3.0 on oneplus 3.
Havoc os has low call volume bug which can be rectified by above changes. 
But ever since I updated to android 10 I am not able to edit the above xml file. 
It's location is /system/vendor/etc.
Editing using any root explorer results in error that given file cannot be moved from tmp folder to etc folder. 
Please provide a way to edit the file. 
It's a read only file system. 
Please suggest a way to mount is at write file system

Comment: Did you [disable `dm-verity`](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215800/218526)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy the file mixer_gains.xml into your internal storage, edit it and copy it back with twrp recoverys file manager.

Comment: That should work. Had the same issue with the latest version of pie...