# How to mount system under super partion?

Tags: adb, root-access, mount, selinux, bind-mount

Google has recently changed the way to mount system and introduced [Dynamic Partitions](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/dynamic_partitions/implement). Previously in a rooted adb shell, I used to run `mount -o rw,remount /system` to mount system in read-write mode. They introduced a new super.img that contains system, vendor, odm, product, etc.

I have a simple question: How can I mount a system from a rooted adb shell in recovery?

After reading the Implementing Dynamic Partitions guide it looks like I have to

1. create system partition dynamically
2. need an entry somewhere where mount point exists
3. mount the system after the above steps.

I don't know how I can do the first step. As the information on the mounting location is inside super.img meta-data and I am unable to read it.

Anyone can put some more light here?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220892

Comment: @alecxs any link to modify system system-less way but without using Magisk? I just want to add `chmod 777 /dev/diag` in init.rc? I read Magisk code but it uses prebuilt-binary so not able to figure out how exactly it patches init.

Comment: Moreover, I have tried to unpack ramdisk and modify recovery init.rc but that didn't work. boot.img doesn't have init.rc strange!

Comment: I mean on a non-system-as-root device. Seeing the same content as https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221180/unable-to-unpack-android-10-boot-img-properly here..

Answer (score 2):

On devices with enough disk space one can convert ext4-dedup dynamic partition into r/w system partition.

This can be done

1. **offline** on linux computer using (official) [Dynamic Partition Tools](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/partition_tools) `lpunpack` and `lpmake` for which precompiled binaries are available from (unofficial) [OTA Tools](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4041843)
2. **offline** on device from TWRP recovery with 3rd party tool [super image dumper](https://github.com/munjeni/super_image_dumper) for which precompiled binaries can be downloaded from XDA [super image tools](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4120963)
3. **online** on device via 3rd party bash script [SystemRW](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/script-android-10-universal-mount-system-read-write-r-w.4247311) running entirely from `/data/local/tmp`