# adb push and wrong slash -> bootloop

Tags: adb

I have my brand new Doogee S96 Pro which is now not able to boot.

I made a great fail:

instead of

```
adb push myfile.zip /sdcard/
```

i wrote

```
adb push myfile.zip \sdcard\
```

From that moment, no more boot.
I can't get what I did, but I now can only boot in the TWRP recovery.

Someone could give me a tip on what I did and how to solve the issue? Thank you.

Comment: flash dm-verity disabler

Comment: thank you for your feedback. Are you talking of the Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt_11.02.2020.zip file?
I don't know what it does, so I'm a bit worried to worsen my situation. 
Should I give a try?

Comment: I tried with Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt_11.02.2020.zip but it doesn't change the situation. How can I know if my device is encrypted? It's brand new, the last time it boot it was in the welcome screen... so i never enabled the encryption. Should I try also with no-verity-opt-encrypt-6.1.zip ? Thank you again for your support.

Comment: that zip will disable [dm-verity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md) and destroy encryption. for FDE encrypted devices flash [no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt) instead. another method is flash 'empty' [vbmeta](https://unofficialtwrp.com/twrp-3-4-0-root-doogee-s96-pro/#Download_Files) partition

Comment: I tried to flash vbmeta.img from fastboot and to format userdata but it still can't boot to android. I always to go TWRP.

Comment: according to fstab.mt6785 this device is running FBE file-based-encryption, but twrp.fstab is for FDE full-disk-encryption. formatting userdata is necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119624/discussion-between-giulio-benetti-and-alecxs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount system under super partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221947)

Comment: At the end I think I got something very wrong in the phone itself, because in 4pda.ru I found an hacked version of boot + vbmeta + super, but flashing it did not solved for me. Probably adb really corrupted something.