# Modifications of vendor image on Android 10

Tags: linux, mount, kernel

There is a vendor image in my device I want to change (unpack/mount, doing changes, pack/umount). My purpose is to update `boot.img` with my new kernel (in a rooted device). Unfortunately, it does not work due to incompatible versions between a newly compiled kernel (my compilation) to the previous kernel modules stored in `vendor.img`. As I figure it, I need to update the old `ko` executables stored in `vendor.img` in my product.

The first step is to do `dd` from my device and `adb pull` it out to my build environment. While I tried to do a mount on `vendor.img`, I discovered it not working due `share_blocks` attribute blocking it to mount as RW (`dmesg` wrote: "...unsupported optional features (4000)"), To solve it, running the following command

```
e2fsck -y -E unshare_blocks vendor.img
```

will disable the `share_blocks` feature that prevented me to do mount as RW. Of course, doing mount RW works correctly.

In the last phase, I tried to replace files in the `vendor` filesystem and then I discovered another challenge into my way, Unfortunately, there was a problem with limited space in the file system,

For example: In case I want to replace the kernel module called `abc.ko`, deleting the file doesn't show any new free space in the file system. At this point, I can't update the old kernel modules with the new ones (compatible with the newly compiled kernel). Of course, running `df -h .` returned no free space and 100% used.

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do?

Comment: I can't, the original partition cannot be change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount system under super partion?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221947/how-to-mount-system-under-super-partion)

Comment: No, As I said, The partition is limited to the vendor partition size !

Answer (score 2):

I know it is almost 2 years ago, but this is solved.

1. Go to this repository: https://sourceforge.net/projects/multi-function-patch/files/RO2RW/. I used this version and the test one successfully: `RO2RW-StableBeta.v3.7.2.1.zip`.
2. You flash it in Magisk with the phone running.
3. Reboot and open up Termux
4. Execute the following commands

   ```
   su
   RO2RW
   ```

The script will walk you through the process. Many options like adding disable force encryption which is a boon to development since TWRP decryption is spotty at best now on a variety of devices. It allows you to resize or repartition in a variety of options.

At the end of the script, it offers a choice of a deblocked `super` for flashing in TWRP style recoveries or one suitable for fastboot work. It dumps the new `super` with a `vbmeta` and `vbmeta_system` image that corresponds to a folder in the internal storage. At this point, you can use a number of tools to dump the `super` and edit it, and then put it back together.

---

All my phones are RW rootfs now. The good old days of wiping out bloatware and having room for new system apps is back.

I am experimenting as we speak with repacking the decrypted RW `super` to include GSI VNDKLite system images. I love a lot of these ROMs but it is such a PITA to get good connectivity and MMS out of them due to the proprietary firmware for the devices and radios.

I am shooting to modify `vendor_boot` and repack the super with the GSI system, but retain the vendor-specific hardware items in the factory firmware in `vendor`, `vendor_boot`, `boot.img/kernel/`, `vendor`, and `product` partitions. I think it's a matter of putting them in the same folder and using common tools for repacking these and editing `vendor_boot`. According to what I have been reading, facilitating this is actually the purpose of the new setup with these bundled ramdisks in `vendor_boot`. If/when I sort it out, I will throw a tutorial up on XDA. I am about to fire this tool off towards that end: https://gitee.com/cfig/Android_boot_image_editor.

---

Other relevant links:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/mkbootimg/+/135c68bdd32ac1bbc4ec4ccb7881e2184d92c890/unpack_bootimg.py
- https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/partitions/vendor-boot-partitions
- https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/doc/android/boot-image.rst

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `vendor` is standalone partition (for `super` partition, refer to other question)

```
adb pull /dev/block/platform/bootdevice/by-name/vendor vendor.img
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G seek=1 count=0 of=vendor.img
resize2fs vendor.img 1G
e2fsck -E unshare_blocks vendor.img
e2fsck -yf vendor.img
adb push vendor.img /dev/block/platform/bootdevice/by-name/vendor
```

that will resize to 1 GB total.

Comment: Thanks, but it's no help me because you cannot enlarge vendor partition.