# Modifications of vendor image on Android 10 - alternative idea

Tags: fastboot, boot, file-system, mount, kernel

Further to my earlier question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241657/modifications-of-vendor-image-on-android-10) and according to the "[Mounting Partitions Early](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/mounting-partitions-early)" article,
I'm looking the correct way to implement my new idea:

1. Skipping the mounting in the startup of vendor in fstab - Its easy to erase the record in fstab related to /vendor partition
2. Doing alternative mount from provided custom vendor image - It's require to know where to inject the mount command

Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in /vendor? What is wrong with Magisk?

Comment: I want to update kernel modules and add more binaries with not limit. The current status is the limited partition. How it is possible to do it with Magisk ? Does Magisk support ? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create Magisk [module](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#magisk-modules) and place your `.ko` kernel modules in

```
/data/adb/modules/my-first-module/system/vendor/lib/modules/example.ko
```

and create script
`/data/adb/modules/my-first-module/service.sh`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
insmod /vendor/lib/modules/example.ko
```

No need to modify `/vendor` partition

Comment: Thanks friend !
Unfortunately, It's not working
Do I need to register my module or do additional thing ?
I did " chmod" to service.sh and to ko to be an execute permission, 
It's not working yet

Comment: I created module.prop file (according to the manual of "[key]=[value]"), and it's still not working. In addition, I don't is any "core-only mode" configuration in setting, after google it I see the Magisk Manager include this conf, after removing Magisk and installation of Magisk Manager it's not working yet.

Comment: install any other module and check modules section (*Busybox for Android NDK* - type *'busybox'* in terminal) if modules not working in general ask Magisk support. Consider *id=my-first-module* is case sensitive. is your module visible? is it enabled? add *'echo "Hello World" >> /data/local/tmp/magisk.log'* in script and check it is executed. check *'ls /vendor/lib/modules/example.ko'* exist