# How to edit in directories like /system or /vendor?

Tags: root-access, lineageos

I'm using LG V20 LOS 18.1. And trying to replace gps.conf from /vendor/etc folder to fix my gps using Root Explorer. I tried to set selinux mode to permissive as I remember worked for me earlier on other devices. Also, tried to type `adb shell` then `su` and `mount -o rw,remount /` using PC with the phone connected and I'm still getting an error: `Operation failed!` when trying to replace the file using Root Explorer. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Check the `mount` command but I assume system and vendor are separate partitions so remounting the root partition doesn't make the writable, too. You can try to remount them separately to allow write. But please make sure to make a backup before messing up these partitions.

Comment: If I type mount -o rw,remount /system, it says `'system' not in /proc/mounts` for some reason.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221947