# Disable avb/dm-verity manually on super partition

Tags: rooting, dm-verity

my doogee s96, with the TWRP no more able to boot, probably due to the dm-verity check.

I tried several things, install Magisk or patching boot.img, but I always failed. The phone starts and suddendly swicth to TWRP without launching Android.

With the suggestion of @alecxs I pulled the super partition through adb and umpacked with lpunpack.

The idea is to manually disable the avb/dm-verity control.

Now I have product.img + system.img + vendor.img.
I can open them with 7z and, for instance, i found many lines on /vendor.img/etc/fstab.mt6785 using avb:

```
system /system ext4 ro wait,,avb=vbmeta_system,logical,first_stage_mount,avb_keys=/avb/q-gsi.avbpubkey:/avb/r-gsi.avbpubkey:/avb/s-gsi.avbpubkey
vendor /vendor ext4 ro wait,,avb,logical,first_stage_mount
product /product ext4 ro wait,,avb,logical,first_stage_mount
```

or the system.img/init.rc with the line

```
exec -- /system/bin/fsverity_init
```

and system.img/system/bin/fsverity_init:

```
# Enforce fsverity signature checking
echo 1 > /proc/sys/fs/verity/require_signatures

# Load all keys
for cert in /product/etc/security/fsverity/*.der; do
  /system/bin/mini-keyctl padd asymmetric fsv_product .fs-verity < "$cert" ||
    log -p e -t fsverity_init "Failed to load $cert"
done

# Prevent future key links to .fs-verity keyring
/system/bin/mini-keyctl restrict_keyring .fs-verity ||
  log -p e -t fsverity_init "Failed to restrict .fs-verity keyring"
```

The question is:

**Is it possible to manually edit the imgs, repack the super and adb push it to make my phone start again?**

What should I do?

Thank you in advance!

### State of the art:

from adb i pulled the superpartition from the device

`adb pull /dev/block/platform/bootdevice/by-name/super super.img`

i extracted it with lpunpack in two folders:

```
./otatools/bin/lpunpack --slot=0 ./super.img ./superA/
```

mounted and enlarged the partition + edited the fstab.mt6785

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw,noexec,noatime vendor.img /mnt/vendor
sudo dd if=./vendor.img bs=1MiB of=./vendor.img conv=notrunc oflag=append count=5 #to add 5MB
sudo losetup | grep vendor #get the right loop device, in my case loop25
sudo losetup -c /dev/loop25
sudo resize2fs /dev/loop25
sudo vim /mnt/vendor/etc/fstab.mt6785 #removed the avb options in vendor, system and product
sudo umount /mnt/vendor
```

Following [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/editing-system-img-inside-super-img-and-flashing-our-modifications.4196625/), I built a new super.new.img:

```
$e2fsck -yf vendor.img
$resize2fs -M vendor.img
$e2fsck -yf vendor.img
$stat -c '%n %s' *
super.img 3758096384
product.img 1596944384
system.img 1128718336
vendor.img 544976896

$../otatools/bin/lpmake --metadata-size 65536 --super-name super --metadata-slots 1 --device super:3758096384 --group main:3270639616 --partition system:readonly:1128718336:main --image system=./system.img --partition vendor:readonly:544976896:main --image vendor=./vendor.img --partition product:readonly:1596944384:main --image product=./product.img --sparse --output ./super.new.img
lpmake I 02-17 12:18:27 2646704 2646704 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition system will resize from 0 bytes to 1128718336 bytes
lpmake I 02-17 12:18:27 2646704 2646704 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition vendor will resize from 0 bytes to 544976896 bytes
lpmake I 02-17 12:18:27 2646704 2646704 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition product will resize from 0 bytes to 1596944384 bytes
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
```

even though the size of super.new.img is not the same of super.img (is it normal??)

```
$stat -c '%n %s' super.new.img
super.new.img **3248851200**
```

when I flash it with adb the phone goes straight to the recovery without booting android. Please note that 3248851200 is not divisible by 512, which is a requirement of lpmake....

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable dm-verity on Android with "user" build type ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215800/how-to-disable-dm-verity-on-android-with-user-build-type-rom)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/119624

Comment: edited the first post to add the state of the art.

Comment: I built the new super file but it doesn't work.@alecxs any idea?

Comment: @alecxs if the `dm-verity` implementation depends on `vold` flag: `verify=` in `fstab`, and the `fstab` entry for super partition is in the DTB, you definitely need to modify the DTB; be it a separate partition or appended to the kernel blob. I've no personal experience with super partition though.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/script-mount-system-as-read-write-android-10.4240703